# Can't set VS Code as default for XML files

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Windows 10 and I just installed VS Code (I've tried both "User" version and "System" version). I want to set it as the default for XML files, but whenever I select it (either by right-clicking on a file and using "Open With" > "Choose another app") or by Settings > Default Apps > Choose Default Apps by File Type, it doesn't "stick": https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUME4.gif

Any suggestions?

UPDATE:

Looks like the problem was fixed via a Windows Update. But now the VS Code icon is not shown:

[image]

Comment: It looks like there's no icon for the `Visual Studio Code` selection.  On my system it shows the darker blue VSCode icon on that blue background it puts behind all of the application icons in the list, whereas on yours it's only the blue background.  That makes me think the `Visual Studio Code` item is no longer tied to an actual application on disk.  Does VSCode show up with the correct icon for any other extensions?  `.bash`, `.csx`, `.dockerfile`, `.fs`, and `.yaml` are some extensions it associated itself with on my system.

Comment: @BACON : there's two kind of....symptoms here. First, someone told me about this issue with Windows: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-files/windows-10-always-open-with-doesnt-work/eea098a9-65e4-444c-acfc-2ea94d3140a8 and also if I look at the default app for .csproj (for instance) the VS code icon doesn't show up there either

Comment: What version of Windows 10 are you running?  I am using 64-bit Windows 10 Pro v1803 Build 17134.345 with a user install of 64-bit VSCode v1.29.1 and I am able to change the default app for `.xml` files without issue.  If you try changing the default app to something other than `Visual Studio Code` does that work?

Comment: Windows 10 Pro, 64 bit, 10.0.17134 Build 17134. At the time I submitted this question on SO, I tried both the latest "User" an "System" installs of VS Code. Also cannot change the default for .xml files to even Notepad++